# Multiple backgrounds with CSS3

Tags: css

At the moment, I'm wresting with a problem where whenever I try to use multiple backgrounds, it either only shows one or none at all. When I add multiple 'background-repeat' properties to go along with each image,it shows nothing at all. When I use only one, it only shows the first listed background.

Here's my code:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 41px 7px black;
background-image: url(images/journalist/header_bg.gif) no-repeat, url(images/journalist/body_top.gif) no-repeat, url(images/journalist/body_tile.gif) repeat-y;
background-size: 100%;
margin: auto auto;
padding: 20px;
text-align: left;
```

You can see where I am attempting to apply it [here](http://arflux-rpg.com/forum).

Comment: background-image for one element is only one. You can mix multiple background using multiple element.

Comment: And also in your link, the background image is only one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've changed it to 'background: ...' and now it's actually showing one image :)

Comment: @Captain, I think you are not getting my point, we cannot use more than one image as background for one image.

Comment: This uses the (semi-new) feature of CSS3 where you can have multiple backgrounds. http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: Well Captian, it says `Browser support for multiple backgrounds is relatively widespread with Mozilla Firefox (3.6+), Safari/Chrome (1.0/1.3+), Opera (10.5+) and even Internet Explorer (9.0+) all implementing the feature.`

Comment: I know, I am using Firefox 4 Beta, which has all CSS3 standards implemented natively.

Comment: I tried your code. Its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing a fiddle or something, but your code uses `background-image` but also specifies background-positions, which is invalid, so the whole declaration gets dropped.

As to why it shows only one when you fix this, I can only guess: Maybe the topmost image (the first one) is hiding the rest? Maybe the rest of the images can't be found?